# Querying a column that contains comma separated values

Tags: sql-server, csv

I'm trying to figure out why my where clause is returning all rows.

I'm querying a column that contains csv's using a variable that also contains csv's. I've built a stored function to split the variable on csv and return a table with one row that contains what I'd like to have on the right side of the LIKE operator.

Example:

The stored function:

```
ALTER Function [dbo].[storedFunction] 
    (@Fields VARCHAR(MAX),
     @Field_Name VARCHAR(MAX) = '')  
RETURN @Tbl_Fields Table (FIELD Varchar(max))  
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FIELD varchar(max) = REPLACE(@Fields, ',', '%''' + ' AND ' + 
@Field_Name + ' Like ' + '''%');

    INSERT INTO @Tbl_Fields 
        SELECT '''%' + @FIELD + '%'''

    RETURN
END
```

Using the stored function:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @variable varchar(max) = 'variable1, variable3';
END

SELECT field 
FROM storedFunction(@variable, 'main_csv_field');
```

returns `'%variable1%' AND main_csv_field Like '%variable3%'`

My simplified query:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @variable varchar(max) = 'variable1, variable3';
END

SELECT main_csv_field 
FROM table
WHERE (main_csv_field LIKE (SELECT field 
                            FROM storedFunction(@variable, 'main_csv_field');
```

returns

```
variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4,...
variable2,variable4,...
variable1,variable3,...
```

My problem is this last query returns all of the rows in the table regardless of value matching. Were I to copy and paste the value returned from the stored function I would get the data that I need.

How/what is the difference here?

Comment: I can't explain your results, but I don't think you can chain multiple likes together that way.  I think you would need to build the statement into a string and use sp_executesql or exec.

Comment: @Obie Thanks for the reply! If I understand like-chaining correctly its totally do-able in this instance. If I replace `(SELECT field FROM storedFunction etc` with the value that it outputs '%var1%' AND field_... LIKE '%var3%', ending up with the clause `WHERE (main_csv_field LIKE '%var1%' AND main_csv_field LIKE '%var3")`. Which is totally valid, and I can chain together dozens of those LIKE statements.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with literal text, but if you set a variable to that text, I don't believe it will work.

Comment: As @Obie mentions - if you want to do something like this, you'll need to build up an sql string using the result of your function, and then execute that entire string. Because you cannot just put some string literal containing sql onto non-dynamic sql and have it run.

Comment: OK!  Thanks yall. This will definitely give me a direction.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I keep getting Incorrect Syntax errors, and I haven't found any information that's explained what I'm doing wrong in a way that I can understand. I was hoping it'd just be as simple as storing the string as a variable and then executing the variable, but I think that I'm not fully understanding whats happening. I'm going to keep researching executing strings, and I'll post back if I get something to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Obie and @AllanS.Hansen I knew where to start looking to fix this. Its pretty rough, but I wanted to post a solution before I got too far down the rabbit hole:

```
DECLARE variable1 varchar(max) = '' --around 9 passed from code

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @column_list varchar(max) = 'column1, column2, etc'
--one of each of the tests per variable passed from code
DECLARE @variable1_test nvarchar(max) = (SELECT CASE WHEN @variable = '' THEN '%' ELSE (SELECT * from dbo.stored_function(@variable, 'column_name')) END);
END;

SET @query = ' SELECT ' + @column_list + ' 
        FROM table_name 
        WHERE variable LIKE ''' + @variable_test + ''' '
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query;
print(@query); --This is just to see the resulting query, which helped me a ton
```

Exciting! Now I have to test it.